# how font-kerning measured font-kerning: 10 x?

Tags: css

i'm trying to change the font-kerning property , but i just can't figure it out how to specify a speicific value for it !

here https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-kerning-prop

nothing mentioned about measured value , like is it in px em or what ?

Comment: As the table in your linked page shows three possible values only, `auto | normal | none`, those are probably your choices, and units are irrelevant.

Comment: thanks for you reply , i'm trying to convert photoshop kerning into letter-spacing css property and i cant figure it out ...... how to convert from Photoshop kerning unit to css px or em ?